# Matlab blockproc store vector result as 3rd dimension

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have images that i need to divide into blocks and then compute histogram for each block. I think the best way of doing this is to compute the histogram for each block with the blockproc() function but the histogram is a vector and i'd like to store it in a 3rd dimension in order to make further computations faster.

for exemple, i have 1024*1024px images, that i divide into 64*64px blocks, and compute the histrogram with hist(). So blockproc should return a 16*16 matrix. But given that hist() returns a vector that i want to store, i'd like to make blockproc() return a 16*16*256 matrix, the 3rd dimension being the 256 values of my histogram.

my current code is:

```
function [ counts ] = getHist( block )
    [counts,]=hist(block.data, 0:255);
end

HistA = blockproc(lbpA, [64 64], @(block_struct) getHist(block_struct));
```

but it returns (16*256) by 1024 matrix.

How could i achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: What does `blockproc` return? If the number of returned elements is OK, you can just [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) later.

Comment: i added a code example, but it is not working as expected. @DedekMraz: it returns (16*256) by 1024 matrix, i don't even understand why it doesn't return a (16*256) by 16 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Matlab here, so this is all untested.

I've read the `blockproc` documentation. I think you get a 2D (16*256) by (16) matrix (or vice-versa). And you want a 16 by 16 by 256 matrix.

Try changing the output of the histogram with [shiftdim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) - your histogram is a row vector with size [1,256].

```
output = shiftdim(output,-1)
```

This should produce a [1,1,256] vector.

I'm asuming you want the count of all pixels in the block, not column by column, which you are doing now. I think reshaping your 64*64 block matrix to a vector with `(:)` should work:

```
function counts = getHist(block)
    counts = hist(block.data(:), 0:255);
end
```

Comment: it's not working, it says "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

Comment: Hm...dimension problem again - how very Matlab :) Could you tell me what the dimension of the `getHist` output is (before and after `shiftdim`)? Could be that histogram already returns a row vector and you should only do `shiftdim(output,-1)`

Comment: So you start with 2^20 pixels. Each 64*64=2^12 pixels become 256=2^8 vector. So the output should have 2^16, but you say the output has 1024*256*16=2^22 elements. The problem: your input is a matrix, not vector. I guess Matlab makes 64 histograms, one for each column. This would explain the dimensions.

Comment: you are right, actually i should have used "counts=hist(block.data(:), 0:255)" otherwise hist makes 1 histogram per column. And using "shiftdim(counts, -1)" now seems to be ok ! thanks!